# Mixing SSD and HDD in a ubuntu server?

Tags: server, hard-drive, configuration, ssd

Is it possible to mix SSD and HDD together in a file server?

I want my configuration to be:
 ~ 4x60GB SSD
 ~ 4x2TB HDD

I will install the ubuntu server into one of the SSD, can I set the partition to use the other 3x60GB+4x2TB?

Comment: What do you mean with "mix" . Each disk will get its own mountpoint. If you mean RAID: if you want that you need to use the same size disks (but that is not an issue with Ubuntu ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Each disk can have its own mount point or you can use [Logical Volume Management (LVM)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm).

I have a configuration with SSD and HDD (but for desktop). Main system is on SSD, and `/home` is on HDD. This configuration works generally fine but I think that it wastes my SSD performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Software RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID), or [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm), as mentioned by @TSr.

If I would set this up, I'd do it like this:

- SSDs:

  - Normal partition on one of the disks for */boot*
  - RAID 1 or 5 array (or the LVM equivalent) on all of the disks with:

    - A large enough swap partition
    - The */* partition
- HDDs:

  - RAID 1 or 5 array (or the LVM equivalent) spanning all of the disks

    - Create a */data* partition on there

If you have more in-depth questions on this, you should probably raise it at: https://serverfault.com/